# find + how to re-edit the files names

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, rhel, find

under folder `/home/files` we have the following  files

```
VER_3all_servers_home\server383_232.35.35.341
VER_3all_servers_home\server323_232.35.35.342
VER_3all_servers_home\server313_232.35.35.343
VER_3all_servers_home\server303_232.35.35.344
VER_3all_servers_home\server381_232.35.35.345
VER_3all_servers_home\server380_232.35.35.346
```

we want to re-edit the files , by remove the word – “`3all_servers_home\`” from all the files under `/home/files`

so the files will be looks like this

```
VER_server383_232.35.35.341
VER_server323_232.35.35.342
VER_server313_232.35.35.343
VER_server303_232.35.35.344
VER_server381_232.35.35.345
VER_server380_232.35.35.346
```

Any suggestion how to do this approach ?

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: we have rhel 7.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
for f in /home/files/*3all_servers_home*; do 
    mv -- "$f" "${f//3all_servers_home\\}"
done
```

The `${var//glob}` format will remove all matches of the glob `glob` from the variable `var`.

Or, if you have `perl-rename` (I don't remember what it is called on Red Hat, it will be one of `rename`, `prename` or `perl-rename`):

```
rename 's/3all_servers_home\\//' /home/files/*3all_servers_home*
```

Comment: not so good because its stuck on "mv: overwrite"

Comment: so you need to add mv -f

Comment: @yael what is `mv: overwrite`? The normal `mv` doesn't produce any such message by default and there are no name collisions in the example you gave. Perhaps your `mv` is aliased to `mv -i`?

Comment: @EdMorton unlikely, but a good reason to use `mv --`, thanks.